# k_means algorithm for an image dataset in matlab

Tags: matlab, k-means

I want to write the code that was proposed in the "VSUMM" article.

In one step there is k-means algorithm. It's written in the article but didn't describe how it'll work. According to the article there is a video at first. The video will be split into frames, then according to some formula the k will be computed and k_mean algorithm get started.

There is a data set of video frames which are images. How could I apply k-means on them?

What I've done till now:

1. Put all images in k groups. Each group in a row of a cell array which the first data of it, is the mean value. this values are the names of images indeed.
2. Calculate the Euclidean distance between each image and the other mean value and I put the images that has minimum distance to previous keys in that group.

But now I'm stuck at the 3rd step, and I don't know what to do.

I've got k group of images in cell array which values are just the name of images but according to k-means the new k is the mean of elements in a group. But these elements in my theory are just the name of images. So what should I do? What should this mean be? Is it correct if i get the mean of images' name?

Comment: If you have the statistics toolbox you might want to consider just using the kmeans function there. Save you all the trouble, debugging, and optimizing. http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kmeans.html

Comment: i can't use k-means function. cause i've got a cell array in which i put the name of images but the Euclidean distance which should be calculated in each step of algorithm is according to distances of frames. i read the images first and calculate it later

Comment: You can compute the feature vectors for each frame (which you will use to compute the euclidean distances between frames) in the order they appear in your cell array first. Then cluster these feature vectors (where there is one feature vector for each frame) using the KMeans Matlab function. You don't have to compute the Euclidean distances, the function will do that for you. Basically you just need to compute the feature vector representation for each frame and let the KMeans function do the rest.

Comment: where have you been all these weeks that i went wrong:_( thank you :D it was so helpful, thank you a million time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) has a good article on the technique of k-means clustering.  Procedurally, you identify a set of items that can be expressed as vectors--- in your case, I think the items are image frames and the vector components are the values of all the pixels in the frame (thousand or million dimensional vectors).  K-means clustering finds k groups of image frames that are similar within each group and dissimilar between groups.  You decide what k is: 5 or 10 or whatever.

First step: randomly define k points in the million-dimensional vector space.  It sounds like you did that.

Second step: for each image frame, find out which of the k points is closest to the frame in question, using Euclidean distance.  It doesn't sound like you did that, but I don't know.

Third step: for each of the k groups, calculate the mean of all the vectors in the group.  That is, do a vector sum of items in the group and divide it by the number of members in the group.  Do that separately for each group.

Fourth step: replace each of the k points by the mean you just calculated.

Then iterate this procedure (steps two theough four) hundreds or thousands of times.  It will gradually approach a solution in which the variance is minimized within each cluster and maximized between clusters.  That is, each group would represent images that are visually similar to each other within the group and are dissimilar from one group to another.

Comment: thanks @jim. i did first and second step completely and i know i should do the 3rd step like you said but my question is how could i? i mean my values are just the name of images. should i calculate the mean of their name and put it as new k ?(in 2nd step when i find the k points according to Euclidean distance to previous k points, i put the name of images in the cell array&)

Comment: It's possible to do clustering on the *names* of the images, rather than the images themselves, as I had assumed.  But you'll need to define a notion of distance over strings--- I wouldn't call any such distance "Euclidean"--- and you'd have to want clusters of similar names as a result.  Is that realy what you want?  It seems like a strange project to me.